# How should I install dropbox in swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, swiftydropbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXCFS.png)

I'm a 
beginner for swift.I installed the cocoapods in swift but I couldn't import the SwiftyDropbox.Can anyone give solution for this issue?

Comment: Just to check, are you sure you installed it to the correct location?  Does it show up if you expand the Pods project in the left bar?

Answer (score 1):

After installing any pods to your project, you must open your project by .xcworkspace file. You can't do it by .xcodeproject or opening it directly in Xcode.